# Spark-submit is re-using previous jar

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, spark-submit

I am attempting to run a simple job via spark submit.  I am doing so as follows:

```
spark-submit --class com.my.namespace.MyJobClass  --master local --deploy-mode client --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=$(echo ./lib/*.jar | tr ' ' ':')  --verbose    hdfs://tmp/jars/mySparkJob.jar  args
```

( Note that I have renamed all the class names etc to "MyJob" style to make things simpler here).  The job submits fine, the main class resolves fine, and i am resolving all my dependencies without an issue.

However, on my initial run i found a bug in `MyJobClass`. So i fixed this, re-packaged `MySparkJob.jar`,  put it back into HDFS and re ran the job.  However, the bug remains. No matter what i do, it seems that SPARK is *re-using my initial version of `MySparkJob.jar`* so i cannot run the updated version of this jar.

I am using spark `2.1.0`  (mapr version: `Running Spark version 2.1.0-mapr-1801`)

I have tried:

- running from local and cluster modes of spark
- decompiling the jar to make sure the code change exists
- renaming the jar and running that - inexplicably it still uses the old code!!
- Use both local and hdfs based versions of the fixed jar
- restarting the resource manager
- deleting spark.yarn.archive -> maprfs:///apps/spark/spark-jars.zip

I feel i must be doing something daft ( it happens!). My question(s) are:

- Do i need to clear anything from spark between jobs?   If so, what do i need to clear and where is this located?
- Does spark effectively zip up my dependencies and place them somewhere? If so where ?
- Any other observations that might assist?

Comment: As I've found out you are submitting your job from the jar file located on hdfs. am I true? If yes, then it's a weird action. If you are worried about your dependencies you can use shaded jar file to solve it. Afterward, try to submit from the jar file sent to master node.

Comment: Weirdly, I'm getting a similar issue - but with a `.py` file, and submitted from local disk (not hdfs).

Answer (score 0):

So .. while posting this question it got me thinking that it makes no sense at all given all the things I've tried,  and that it must be something i was doing wrong.   After inspecting the jars that were included in the `libs` folder, it seemed that there was an old sbt artifact present, ( code was packaged with `sbt universal:stage`) which seems to be an old version of my main lib ( which must have been hanging around in ivy cache or something but for reasons unknown, sbt was including it).   As it contained the same main class i believe that Spark was using that code vs the jar i was submitting ( likely to do with how class paths are being resolved).  After deleting this file from the lib folder, my job appears to run fine and uses the newer code. I have new issues to resolve now, (they are separate/different so I won't include them here and convolute the question), but this seems to at least have explained why I've been seeing this weird behavior.